# How to mirror a rigged object

Tags: game-engine, rigging, objects

I've created an object and have parented the object to a rig. Now I want to have this object twice and mirrored. Now the problem, if I mirror a copy of the object and go into the Gamemode (pressing <kbd>P</kbd>) the pose of the rigged object changes. I`ve searched a lot on the internet to try and solve this problem but I haven't found anything yet.

---

In this example I gona show you my problem. If I copy a rigged Object with the armature and mirror it (ctrl m) and then go in to gamemode the copyed object gets shown in an other way

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you mirror? In edit mode or in object mode? Did you mirror the armature too? Are the already applied vertex groups still correct?

Comment: I`ve mirrored in object mode with the armature and the vertex groups still are correct

Comment: I just tested with a very simple character. I could not discover an issue. Could it be you have some bone constraints? Can you provide a demo file?